# A specific but basic tutorial for Corona SDK?

Tags: corona-sdk

I have been looking at Corona SDK and it would be helpful if I could see a tutorial/example to accomplish the following:

1. Load an image as a background/map
2. Draw a circle on the screen
3. user can tap elsewhere and the circle moves to that location (this can be repeated)

Does anyone know of any examples out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy to do - here's a plug and play sample;

```
local background = display.newRect( 0, 0, 320, 480 )
background:setFillColor(0, 200, 255)

local circle = display.newCircle( -100, 0, 20 )

local function moveCircle(event)
    circle.x = event.x
    circle.y = event.y
end
background:addEventListener("tap", moveCircle)
```

Though obviously you'd you an image, I'm using a rectangle.